# Prime-ng - Get the checked rows from p-table in button click in angular

Tags: angular, primeng

I used p-table in angular application and displaying the data with checkbox as header and checkbox for each row. Now I want to get the checked rows from p-table on the button click (button is outside the p-table).

```
    <p-table #dt [value]="dispReturnTags" [columns]="cols" dataKey="id" [(selection)]="selected">
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 3rem">
            <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
        </th>
        <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
            {{col.header}}
        </th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-dispReturnTags let-columns="columns">
    <tr class="p-selectable-row" [pSelectableRow]="dispReturnTags">
        <td>
            <p-tableCheckbox [value]="dispReturnTags"  ></p-tableCheckbox>
        </td>
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
            <!-- <span class="p-column-title">{{col.header}}+"2"</span> -->
            {{dispReturnTags[col.field]}}
        </td>
        <td>
            
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

What event we should write to get the selected items in typescript file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special to get the selected items.

You are already using `[(selection)]="selected"` which is an in-built 2-way binding. So the `selected` refers to an array in your component file and would be having all your selected items.

Comment: I am able to get the elements in the component file using the selected. Thanks for your help

Comment: thats a big help